# Pygame libpng warning

Tags: python, pygame, png, libpng, pgzero

When I run my pygame program, an error saying 'libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image' keep happens. Although it doesn't seem to affect the program, I don't like seeing it. I saw the answer saying 'convert png-24 image to png-8 image', but I don't want to. Is there any other way to fix it? I'm currently using 64 bit python 3.6.5, and pygame 1.9.4.

Comment: Same here, 64bit Python 3.7.1 / pygame 1.9.4.

Answer (score 0):

There's an issue tracking this bug here: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/641